# Workstationid property in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Here I need to get a string that identifies the database client using PostgreSQL with C#. Here is the following example.

**Example**:

```
private static void OpenNpgsqlConnection(string connectionString)
{
     using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("WorkstationId: {0}", connection.WorkstationId);
     }
}
```

**Error**:

```
'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Workstationid'.
```

Comment: ... and where is this property supposed to come from? Where do you store it? Identifies what aspect of the database client? From where? (Are you looking for `application_name`?)

Comment: @Craig Ringer, In SQL Server it comes from Namespace : `System.Data.SqlClient` and Assembly : `System.Data in (System.Data.dll)`. I want to know that is it present in PostgreSQL or not?

Comment: Well, your code shows that it is not. Perhaps it would help if you explained what you actually want to achieve. What problem this is meant to solve.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, The above code was just the example. I actually want to know that "How do I get network name of the client using the property WorkstationID(in SQL Server) in PostgreSQL"?

Comment: where "network name" is the Windows client hostname, like "mycomputer.clients.mycompany.com" in AD? Or the "mycomputer" part of it? Get it from where - if you're running the above code on the client you already know the network name. So where's the code supposed to run? On the PostgreSQL server? This is hopelessly vague.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, I am really sorry. I think i am unable to introduce my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mean the MS SQL specific property [`WorkstationId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.workstationid(v=vs.110).aspx) of `SQLConnection.`

This is an MS SQL specific property. It does not exist for nPgSQL, though of course you could add it.

The documentation in MSDN is profoundly useless, so it's hard to tell what it's actually for.  At a wild guess, I think you probably mean something like PostgreSQL's [`application_name`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME) - a way for the *server* to find out information about the *client* from within a  stored procedure or function.

client drivers or applications have to set `application_name`; there's nothing that gets set automatically to the "network name". (What would that even mean if the client was not a Windows box?). Your application could set `application_name`, either in the connection string or via an explicit `SET` command.

You can also run arbitrary `SET` commands. E.g you might decide to store the "workstation name" in the `myapp.workstationid` connection property. So you:

```
SET myapp.workstationid = 'BOBSCOMPUTER';
```

from your app, after making the initial connection.

Stored procedures can now access it with `current_setting('myapp.workstationid')`.

Note that in both cases, a user with the ability to send raw SQL can just replace these settings with whatever they want. So don't use them for security.